# Application_Start is not firing in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, global-asax

In my web application, I had given some set of coding's in the **APPLICATION_START() in Global.asax** file. Its been working while I run it on the development server. Whereas, when I hosted it in IIS, the **Application_Start event is not firing**. Can any one help me to get rid of this... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's not firing at all? Or did you set a breakpoint and are you waiting for it to be hit?

Comment: No.. Its not at all firing. I just did some Database works in it.

Comment: Its run but you probably get an exception there ! (on IIS) If you run the IIS on Integrated mode, then the `request` is not available there and you have an exception, but you do not see it and you believe that is not run.

Answer (score 2):

No idea if this is your situation, but in case it helps, this happened to me with the following conditions:

- I am using *Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper*
- The IIS application pool is set to use *Integrated Pipeline* mode (it works ok with Classic)
- I do not have a `PreApplicationStartMethod` defined.

(This arose because I was trying to use Ninject.Web 3.0 in a web forms application. It relies on `WebActivator` which is unsigned and so I can't use it easily with my signed assemblies. So I tried to call `NinjectWebCommon.Start()` from `Application_Start()` manually which works fine with the debug webserver but not with IIS in integrated mode.)

Comment: Use _Classic_ which works ok. Or define a `PreApplicationStartMethod` and then _Integrated_ works too.

Comment: Just have similar issue. I spent 1 whole day working on it. Turns out that some guy didn't put all the DLL in. And instead of fail somewhere, the container is always set null... I still not understand that part.

Comment: At least, configuring logging(log4net) is the single best thing I did when working with IIS. If only relying on **** Microsoft Event Viewer Log, I cannot realize the DLL error.