# Application_Start is not being called in IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that I recently added a Global.asax to.

When I run in Visual Studio it works fine, but I put it on my brand new Windows Server 2012 R2 server and `Application_Start()` is not called.

I am sure it is not called because I added:

```
throw new ApplicationException("The End is .... HERE!");
```

at the start of the method.  It throws on start up as expected when run from visual studio, but when run from IIS it is not thrown.

I saw this question: [Application_Start is not firing in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091534/application-start-is-not-firing-in-iis)
But setting to "Classic" did not work...

**How can I get IIS to call my `Application_Start()` on startup?**

Comment: Did you deploy the global.asax file too?

Comment: @AdrianIftode You are AWESOME!!!!  I had not copied that to the Server.  Post that as answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploy on server the `global.asax` file too.